# Identify a branch change from node

Tags: node.js, git, events, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is there a way in which I can know when a user switches git branches from a node process? I am working on a vscode extension and would like to be able to know when such happens. e.g an event fired etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found this library git-emit https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-emit, that listens to file events in git hook files and raises node events from there. Does exactly what I wanted. It supports a wide range of events too.